# Using setValue of EntryView() instead of setPlaceholder

Tags: swift, io

I'm setting the Placeholder value of a EntryView() in my application to a value I'm retrieving from my database. But now I want to change my approach and instead set the value of the EntryView so that the user does not have to fill in the content.

This is my code to retrieve the value and then set the Placeholder:

```
let firstName = dict["firstName"] as? String
```

...

```
self.firstNameEntryView.setPlaceholder(firstName!)
```

This functionality works fine and it populates the correct value as the placeholder. But how do I make the String value of 'firstName' be set as the actual value in my firstNameEntryView?

I tried this approach:

```
self.firstNameEntryView.setValue(String?.self, forKey: firstName!)
```

But I get this error: " setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Thomas"

Thomas is the correct value from my db. Am I using the setValue method incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out through trial and error.

The code to set the text is as follows:

```
self.firstNameEntryView.textField.text?.append(firstName!)
```